# Reading data in from file and inserting into Linked List C++

Tags: c++, file, function, insert, linked-list

For this program, I have to read in a list of names from a txt file and create a new node for each name, then insert the node into a linked list and keep it sorted as new names are read in. I am having difficulty properly reading in the file line by line, and creating a new node and putting the data in. I am very new to linked lists, but the logic seems sound in my insert function, and I think my errors are caused by my syntax. 
Here is my main so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "SortedLinkList.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
   SortedLinkList<string> sll;    //create sortedlinklist object
   SortedLinkList<string> sll2;

   ifstream infile("List1.txt");
   if(infile.fail()) {
      cout << "the input file could not be opened" << endl;
      exit(0);
   }
   else {
      cout << "Opening file 1" << endl;
      string s;
      while (infile >> s)
      {
        infile >> sll;         
        sll.insert(s); //attempting to create new node and use data read 
                         from file
      }
   }
}
```

Here is my insert function. Which is in "SortedLinkList.h"
The class is templated, and a Node.h class has already been provided,
which has the getData() and getNext() function already. The variables current,head,previous, and count have all been declared. The "node.h" file is #included in the "SortedLinkList.h".

```
template <class T>
void SortedLinkList<T>::insert(const T & value)
{
    cout << "insert data" << endl;
    //allocate a node with new
    Node<T> *newNode, *current, *previous;
    newNode = new Node<T>(value);
    current = head;
    previous = 0;
    while(current != NULL)
    if(head == 0)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        SortedLinkList* current = head;
        SortedLinkList* previous = 0;

        //traverse list to find ins. location
        while(current != 0)
        {
            if(current->getData() >= newNode->getData())
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                previous = current;
                current = current->getNext();
            }
        }
        //insert at head
        if(current == head)
        {
            newNode->getNext() = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
        //insert after head
        else
        {
            newNode->getNext() = current;
            previous->getNext() = newNode;
        }
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think there are errors in your code?

Comment: I've tried compiling just that part of the main and the insert function, and it doesn't compile. I've included all the necessary variables (as far as I know) and the "node.h" class also.

Comment: Please add the compiler error messages to your post.

Comment: The compiler says there are two errors, but the error messages are really long.

Comment: the errors are past the character limit

Answer (score 0):

The following lines look like you added the types, `SortedLinkList*`, by mistake.

```
    SortedLinkList* current = head;
    SortedLinkList* previous = 0;
```

You already have declarations for `current` and `previous` at the beginning of the function:

```
Node<T> *newNode, *current, *previous;
```

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
    current = head;
    previous = 0;
```

The error you posted corresponds to the line:

```
        infile >> sll;
```

Looking at what you are doing, you can just remove that line.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't caught that. Unfortunately I'm still getting a really long error message, though the compiler only says there are two.

Comment: Many of them have this format, but with different types /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/istream:201:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'SortedLinkList<string>' to 'basic_ios<char_type, traits_type> &(*)(basic_ios<char_type, traits_type> &)' for 1st argument
    basic_istream& operator>>(basic_ios<char_type, traits_type>&

Comment: Since you have at least three files you are dealing with, perhaps you could put everything in just one .cpp file and remove code line by line until you are able to reduce the number of compiler errors to something that you can understand yourself or be able to post them here.

Comment: I have put everything into one cpp file (excluding node.h) and these are the errors I get:

Comment: /Volumes/Storage/Dropbox/Classes/Data Structures/Program1/test.cpp:40:12: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char>') and 'SortedLinkList<string>')
                                infile >> sll;                                                                      
/Volumes/Storage/Dropbox/Classes/Data Structures/Program1/test.cpp:85:23: error: expression is not assignable
                        newNode->getNext() = head;

Comment: the rest are just "notes"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That makes sense, the infile >> sll; was redundant. I think the reason I'm getting the other error is that I don't need the very last if-else statement in my insert function.